# targeting a button inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Im trying to target a button on a form inside a iframe but its not working, so my question is how do i target a button thats inside a iframe, any help is appreciated thank you.

this is what I have and ive tested it on my site to make sure jquery was working and it does but im just not able to get the button within the iframe.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        /*iframe name is #innerdiv*/
      $("#innerdiv #btnGoBorrow").click(function(){
        $("#outerdiv").slideToggle();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access elements within an `iframe`. However, elements contained in the `iframe` can access your page using `window.top`.

> Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the
>   same-origin policy, and cannot access most of the properties in the
>   other window object if it was loaded from a different domain. This
>   also applies to a script inside a frame trying to access its parent
>   window. Cross-domain communication can still be achieved with
>   `window.postMessage`.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe#section_5).

Comment: can you give me an example of how its used please

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#innerdiv").contents().find("#btnGoBorrow").click()`.  Watch out for same origin policy though (i.e. domains, protocols, and ports must match between the iframe and parent page).